# Remapping the Eureka context

Tags: spring-cloud

Out of the box, eureka provides information at "/"  as in "http://localhost:8761/".

Is there an easy way to move change this context?  Say for example, I want to have this"http://localhost:8762/services" instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I experimented and figured out how this works.
If you change the context path on the your server as below then the ui page at http:/localhost:8761/services is where you find your service information.  Also make sure you change the tests that you have for this.

```
server:
  port: 8761
  contextPath: /services
```

Then in each service add the discovery service info for the client as follows:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/services/eureka/
```

The context must be there.  Then it works

Comment: You can also change `eureka.dashboard.path` (default is "/") to just change the dashboard and not the /eureka endpoints.